# Adding an XML attribute in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, xml-parsing

I have an XML data in the following form:

```
<string name="app_name">my App</string>
<string name="yes">Yes</string>
<string name="no">No</string>
<string name="done">Done</string>
```

I'm trying to write a Bash script for converting the XML to something like this:

```
<string comment="for more see http://www.web.com/test/app_name" name="app_name">my App</string>
<string comment="for more see http://www.web.com/test/yes" name="yes">Yes</string>
```

I did some search and here's what I have found so far.

The code below is making a replacement is every element:

```
 sed -i 's/<string/<string comment=\"for more see http:\/\/www\.web\.com\/test\/\"    /g' string.xml
```

And this expression fetches the `name` attribute:

```
Sname=$(sed '/name/s/\(.*name=\)\(.*\)/\2/' string.xml|awk -F\" '{print $2}')
```

But I have no idea how to merge them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unsafe to use `sed`, or `awk` for XML parsing. These tools are very flexible, but they have no built-in XML parsing features. It is very tedious and impractical to implement an XML parser in `sed`, or `awk`. I recommend using an XML parser such as [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (which is actually more than a parser).

**Example**

```
xmlstarlet ed -a '//string[@name]' -t attr -n comment src.xml | \
  xmlstarlet ed -u '//string/@comment' \
  -x 'concat("see http://www.web.com/test/app_name/", ../@name)' > out.xml
```

The first `xmlstarlet` command parses `src.xml` file, appends an empty `comment` attribute to all `string` tags having `name` attribute (using `'//string[@name]'` [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression). The output of the command is passed to the second command through [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) (`|`).

The second command reads XML from the pipeline, and updates the `comment` attributes with the [`concat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-concat) function which, in particular, concatenates the static string `"see http://www.web.com/test/app_name/"` with the value of `name` attribute (`../@name` stands for "*`name` attribute of the parent node*").

The output of the second command is [redirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) to `out.xml` file.

*Sample Input*

```
<root x="10">
  <string name="app_name">my App</string>
  <string name="yes">Yes</string>
  <string name="no">No</string>
  <string name="done">Done</string>
</root>
```

*Sample Output*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root x="10">
  <string name="app_name" comment="see http://www.web.com/test/app_name/app_name">my App</string>
  <string name="yes" comment="see http://www.web.com/test/app_name/yes">Yes</string>
  <string name="no" comment="see http://www.web.com/test/app_name/no">No</string>
  <string name="done" comment="see http://www.web.com/test/app_name/done">Done</string>
</root>
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for perfect solution, I changed xml to xmlstarlet and it is working like charm. Can you explain how it works, parameters and explanation if possible  for sake of learning

Comment: @user2299735, added some extra info. Please accept the answer, if you think it fixes your problem.